# toggle menu - sub menu on click - jQuery / HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I have this menu:

```
      <div id="menu">
            <div class="header">Menu Header</div>
            <ul>
                <li>asdfsadfdsaf</li>
                <li>sadfsadf</li>
                <li>asdfasdf</li>
                <li>asdfsadf</li>
                <li>asdfsadf</li>
            </ul> 
         </div>
```

How can I do, so whenever I click on one of the links inside each LI, a new sub-menu will toggle in "under" the clicked one?

Comment: Have you looked at the jquery click event handler? One of the easiest ways would be to have attach a click event listener to each of the li's and have it show or hide another set of ul/li elements that are contained in the current one. This requries a bit of css work as well. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple menu pattern to follow:

http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/jejNy/

Comment: He wrote "click", so you could just replace mouseenter with a click :D

Answer (score 0):

First, you need different markup:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="header">Menu Header</div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>Menu item</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Submenu item</li>
                <li>Submenu item</li>
                <li>Submenu item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Menu item</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Submenu item</li>
                <li>Submenu item</li>
                <li>Submenu item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul> 
</div>
```

And simply apply the css and js to the submenu, just like u did with the mainmenu